# How do I calculate Allan Variance (maybe for pulsars)?

Tags: time, software, pulsar

I am studying pulsar timing this summer and have come across many Allan Deviation plots that include several popular clocks alongside pulsar measurements, like this one by [N. Ashby and D.A. Howe](https://tf.nist.gov/general/pdf/2166.pdf): [image: Fractional Frequency Stability]

I am unclear as to where to start. What equation would be appropriate? I have pulsar timing data from the [NANOGrav Public Data Set](https://data.nanograv.org/), which I am able to view through Tempo2 (aka will be able to view it as soon as I figure out how Tempo2 works). If there is other software anyone would recommend for this task that would also be helpful.

I am also unsure where the data for the other clocks would be publicly available. I am hoping a scientist who has done a similar calculation can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after some discussion and paper reading I learned of the sigma_z calculation in this paper by [Matsakis, Taylor, and Eubanks](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?1997A%26A...326..924M&defaultprint=YES&filetype=.pdf). Several astronomers recommended this to me. I was also told to try out Stable32, although I'm not sure if that will work for pulsars. The code for a sigma_z calculation can be found here: [sigma_z calculation](https://tycho.usno.navy.mil/pulsar/sigmaz/sigmaz.html). I believe this is the best method for doing what I asked.